# SDL create transparent surface

Tags: sdl

I was searching for how to create a transparent surface in SDL, and I found the following: http://samatkins.co.uk/blog/2012/04/25/sdl-blitting-to-transparent-surfaces/

Basically, it is:

```
SDL_Surface* surface;
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE,width,height,32, 0xFF000000, 0x00FF0000,        0x0000FF00, 0x000000FF);
#else
surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE,width,height,32, 0x000000FF, 0x0000FF00, 0x00FF0000, 0xFF000000);
#endif
```

and it works, but it seems pretty damn awful to me, so I was wondering if there is some better way of doing this.

Comment: Why do you feel it's awful?

Comment: Because something like creating a transparent surface should be properly handled by the api, instead of the user having to use conditional compilation and hard coded constants.

Comment: From the looks of it, that code doesn't have much to do with transparency. It has more to do with the ordering of the data. As in, is it in little or big endian form.

Comment: Yes, but you need to use an endian dependent constant to make a transparent surface, what I was wondering is if there's a more "proper" way to do this that doesn't require magic numbers like that.

Comment: Using raw data, so unfortunately no. There may be a way to create an elegant solution here but it really isn't needed.

Comment: You could always pull the numbers from a config file so it doesn't have to be hard coded. You could pick a value that is the same in either endian so that you don't need the conditional compilation.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a check to see if the computer uses big endian or little endian. SDL is multiplatform, and computers use different endiannness.

The author of that article was writing it in a "platform agnostic" manner. If you are running this on a PC, you'll probably be safe just using:

```
surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE,width,height,32, 0x000000FF, 0x0000FF00, 0x00FF0000, 0xFF000000);
```

You don't need the conditionals.

That being said, the code will not be portable to other platforms that use big endiandess

Comment: I know what the check is for. I do want it to be portable. I was wondering if there is an alternative to using hard coded constants at all.

Comment: It's more of a compile-time check/option than a program logic option. The way the author presents it is actually preferred because the compiler will just take what it wants and strip it out. Ugly? Somewhat. That's just one of the ways C rolls.

Comment: I know it's a compile time check. What i wanted was to find out if some CreateTranparentSurface function existed that would be a better solution, but clearly it doesn't. :P

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately not. Welcome to the wonderful world of super low level coding. It's ugly :)

Comment: Ah well, hopefully someone who needs it will find this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of experience with SDL2 with my IT class. But I've been developing a simplified version of functions to that use SDL and the way I load my images is is like this:

```
ImageId LoadBmp(string FileName, int red, int green, int blue){
SDL_Surface* image = SDL_LoadBMP(FileName.c_str()); // File is loaded in the SDL_Surface* type variable

GetDisplayError(!image, string("LoadBmp:\n Couldn't load image file ") + FileName); // Check if the file is found

Images.push_back(image); // Send the file to the Images vector


SDL_SetColorKey(Images[Images.size() - 1], SDL_TRUE, // enable color key (transparency)
    SDL_MapRGB(Images[Images.size() - 1]->format, red, green, blue)); // This is the color that should be taken as being the 'transparent' part of the image

                                                                      // Create a texture from surface (image)
SDL_Texture* Texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, Images[Images.size() - 1]);
Textures.push_back(Texture);

return Images.size() - 1; // ImageId becomes the position of the file in the vector}
```

What you would probably looking for is

```
SDL_SetColorKey(Images[Images.size() - 1], SDL_TRUE, // enable color key (transparency)
SDL_MapRGB(Images[Images.size() - 1]->format, red, green, blue)); // This is the color that should be taken as being the 'transparent' part of the image
```

by doing so, you set the RGB given to be considered as transparent. Hope this helps! Here's the SDL Ready Template I'm currently working on you should be able to use some of those!
https://github.com/maxijonson/SDL2.0.4-Ready-Functions-Template

Answer (score -1):

Actually we call it Alpha blending and you can look at it here:
http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/13_alpha_blending/index.php